# Remove displaying bundle product price +£0.00 in shopping cart

Tags: php, html, magento, shopping-cart

I have had a look through the code that I can see that would be linked to displaying this but have not had any luck.

We have some bundled products, of which you can change accessories (i.e. colour/plugs) which have a price of £0.00 (have managed to remove this from the actual product page). However on the shopping basket they show, is there anyway to just remove or hide the price. See image for a clearer understanding:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the html for that row (let me see if css can be use to hide it)? Do you have other bundle product that have a price associate with it that need to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to remove it from all items regardless of the price, then you could add this css

```
#shopping-cart-table dd span.price{
    display:none;
}
```

If you only want to remove the price if it is zero, the you could take a look at /app/design/frontend/default/{theme path}/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml (around line # 46)

- Figure out where it is add the price and only append the price if it is greater than 0

or

- Do a find a replace `str_replace("£0.00", "", $_formatedOptionValue['value'])` on the string that display that line (make sure to add the currency sign so that £10.00 dont get replace)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try 
`.item-options dd span.price{
    display:none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution working but its not a way to solve this issue. I have one solution for you, so can you please try this :)

Open `Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration.php`

```
public function getBundleOptions(ItemInterface $item){

}
```

Remove price from this function.

Thanks